# Why selectedIndex doesn't work in my code?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a following, easy example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
  <option>Pineapple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</select>


<script>
document.addEventListener("change", function () {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  var y = x.options[x.selectedIndex];
  alert(y);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

when I choose option on my list then no alert pops-up. I also tried with:

```
var y = x.options[x.selectedIndex].index;
```

but can't return index number of given option. When I use .text instead of .index (to get text from option) it also doesn' work

Comment: You should open the console and check for errors. Your code has unbalanced parentheses. Should be closed as typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax issue (missing the `addEventListener` closing parenthesis).

```js
document.addEventListener("change", function () {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  var y = x.options[x.selectedIndex].index;
  alert(y);
}); // missing ) here
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
  <option>Pineapple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to access the `textContent` from the selected option ?
(because its `value` is directly accessible on the select)

the event listener must also be used on the select, to use a `this`

```js
const mySelect = document.getElementById('my-select')

mySelect.addEventListener("change", function ()
  {
  console.clear()
  console.log( 'value=', this.value, ' || content=', this.options[this.selectedIndex].textContent)
  })
```

```html
<select id="my-select">
  <option value="A">Apple</option>
  <option value="O">Orange</option>
  <option value="P">Pineapple</option>
  <option value="B">Banana</option>
</select>
```

Comment: when I write: ```document.addEventListener("change", function () {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  var y = x.options[x.selectedIndex].index;
  alert(y);
})``` then don't need to use eventListener on the select, it works fine

Comment: @Muska then you get ALL the events change on everything in the document, also on other elements of your page which are not your select